# what is the size of the packets in Solaris OS

Tags: solaris, packet

I need to figure out the size of the packets on solaris OS. When I run this command:

```
netstat -in
```

I get this output in terms of number of packets:

```
 netstat -in
Ipkts Ierrs    Opkts Oerrs  Coll
2450315175     0 1850696874     0     0
2450315175     0 1850696874     0     0
2450315175     0 1850696874     0     0
2450315175     0 1850696874     0     0
2450315175     0 1850696874     0     0
2450315175     0 1850696874     0     0
```

Does anybody know the size of the packets in terms of bits/bytes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`netstat` doesn't report the packets size.

You can use `kstat` to retrieve both the number of packets and bytes sent and received in deduce the average packet size.